# Why does len(str(int)) = 13?

Tags: python, string, class, string-length

I was doing some python and noticed that:

```
print(len(str(int))
```

yields 13.
To be clear, int is just the integer class, no variable assigned to it. You could run just this code and it yields 13.
Now that I think about it, could it be printing the length of 'string' and 'integer' together? If so, why?

Comment: The length of the string `"<class 'int'>"` is 13 characters

Comment: Because classes have a `__str__` and `__repr__` representations too, for `int` it's `<type 'int'>`.

Comment: Did you try printing `str(int)` first?

Answer (score 1):

`str(int)` returns `<class 'int'>`, which is 13 characters in length.

Answer (score 1):

On your interpreter you type `int`:

```
>>> int
<class 'int'>
>>>
```

It will be `<class 'int'>` as result.

So convert it into a string would a string as `"<class 'int'>"`, which contains 13 characters.

Whole example building-up to that:

```
>>> int
<class 'int'>
>>> str(int)
"<class 'int'>"
>>> len(str(int))
13
>>>
```